# SubRow After Expanding a Parent Row in extjs41

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, expander, rowexpansion

Requirement is simple with showing a row(child Row) when user clicks on the Parent Row.

Attached image for more info[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the grid grouping feature: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping

Answer (score 0):

I guess simple tree panel with multiple columns can fit your requirements perfectly.

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14d6).

Comment: Thanks fr ur reply... since i am using 4.1 which does not show the Price and change part as per ur Fiddle....

Comment: since i am new to tree view, will the functionalities (Like changing background color of the row, making the test bold) wlll work on the tree panel......

Comment: @Subratnayak. I think so since both `Ext.grid.Panel` and `Ext.tree.Panel` base on `Ext.panel.Table` (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table) as well as it views based on `Ext.view.Table`.